# Какую формулу надо прописать в условном форматировании google sheets, чтобы при заполнении ячейки определенным значением закрашивалась эта же строка?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Какую формулу надо прописать в условном форматировании google sheets, чтобы при заполнении ячейки определенным значением закрашивалась эта же строка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример для первых пяти строк. 
Диапазон A1:Z5
Форматировать ячейки, если "Ваша формула"
И если по ячейках в столбце E значение <=100

=($E1<=100)

Формат который нужен.

Comment: [По-моему не работает](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ow8Gr85nB1uFSWuMU6cMS8lPainckBDI/view?usp=sharing)
@Сергей-Белоус

Comment: И вопрос еще в том, как протянуть формулу, то есть, чтобы в каждой следующей строке формула сдвигалась на один ряд, а не ссылалась всегда на одну и ту же ячейку.

Comment: $E1, $Е закрепляет столбец E, 1 первая ячейка которая будет меняться, если поставить $1 то будет ссылка только на первую ячейку, например $E$1. Попробуйте такую формулу =($E178="Daily need") Перед скобками =